# Angular reading text from PDF using ng2-pdf-viewer or more optimal way?

Tags: angular, pdf

My task is to write an Angular component where I have to compare two PDF's based on their text. I'm currently struggling to find the most efficient way to get it done.

At the moment I have a test project with ng2-pdf-viewer set up but I do not understand how to read the text from that pdf. Do I need to iterate through every `<div>` element to get each part of the text?

Greatly appreciate any suggestions or hints for my project!